# autoload bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple question, the bootstrap tooltip works on particular selector[tag] on hover[mouseover] as default i.e you need to hover on the tag to activate the tooltip or make it appear. I want to make it appear in an input tag when i left the tag or when cursor leaves that input tag automatically, not on hover[mouseover]...

The question at hand is by default the tooltip works on following

```
('selector').tooltip('show');
```

Is there anyway to make it according to my specifications above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
$('input').tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
}).on({
    blur: function() {
        $(this).tooltip('show');
    },
    focus: function() {
        $(this).tooltip('hide');
    }
});
```

Example here - http://jsfiddle.net/UPRbm/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    if(!window.jQuery)
    {
        alert('jQuery not loaded');
    }
    else
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#example').tooltip({'placement':'top', 'trigger' : 'manual'});

            $('#example').blur(function() {
                 $('#example').tooltip("show");
                 setTimeout("$('#example').tooltip('hide');", 1000);
            });
        });


    }
}
```